# one to one relationship in Phalcon model not returning object

Tags: php, phalcon

I have two models in Phalcon .I am getting the model object of the first model using the `Placon Model::find()`. 
The problem is I cannot get model object which has an one to one relation with the first model.

I have tried everthing given in Phalcon tutorial.

Gave hasone in first Model on initialize

```
 public function initialize()
 {
     $this->hasOne("emp_id", "Employee", "emp_id");
 }
```

Where emp_id is the primary key of Employee table and Foreign key in Salary table, which is my second model.

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to specify the relation between 2 models, and how those two models are related. To get one-to-one relation object you can use `hasOne` relation  or `hasMany` for many-to-many relations.

```
  $this->hasOne('emp_id', '(path to your model)', 'emp_id', array(
                'alias' => 'employeeId',
                'reusable' => true
            ));
```

Ex: if you have a `Employee` object and you need access the one-to-one related objects you must use `Employee.employeeId` to get the related object.